# Vue - Cannot pass props to Dynamically imported Web Component

Tags: vue.js, webpack, web-component

my old friend.

I am routing to a vue file which is imported async (via import) upon routing. Its template is below, it mostly exists to load in a thicker web component, and provide separation from that thicker component (called mcclure-events).

```html
<template>
  <mcclure-events :userState="userState"></mcclure-events>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'mCclureEvents',
  components: {},
  props: {
    userState: Object
  },

  // Example of import statement used.
  mounted () {
    import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ './mcclure-events.min.js')

  },

  // Importing here did not help.
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {

  }
}
</script>
```

I am fetching `mcclure-events` by bypassing webpack and communicating with a server.

mcclure-events is a web-component in a separate project built via:

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name mcclure-events
```

I am on Vue 2.6.1

mcclure-events is not being assigned userState.

I have tried to...

- fetch mcclure-events before the stub file is fetched
- fetch mcclure-events after the stub is fetched, but before being routed to
- and after the stub is routed and mounted.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks odd. You are importing the file but not assigning it anywhere and more importantly, not registering the component.

Typically this is how you import a component dynamically in vue:

```js
export default{
    components: {
        'mcclure-events': () => import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ './mcclure-events.min.js')
    }
}
```

Try it that way and see if that helps.

Comment: This fetches the component, but the component is not mounted. I changed the way the router utilizes the stub component ```mCclureEvents``` from ```component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "mCclureEvents" */ '../views/mCclureEvents.vue')
``` to a standard import statement, which has the same effect